# How to retrieve and update a file > 1MB from/to master GitHub using Octokit.Net Git Data API within c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, octokit, github-api-v3

I am trying to read and update a single file in my repository using Octokit.Net.

The particular file I am trying to read/update is about 2.1MB in size so when I attempt to read this file using the following code...

```
var currentFileText = "";

            var contents = await client.Repository.Content.GetAllContentsByRef("jkears", "NextWare.ProductPortal", "domainModel.ddd", "master");
            var targetFile = contents[0];
            if (targetFile.EncodedContent != null)
            {
                currentFileText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(targetFile.EncodedContent));
            }
            else
            {
                currentFileText = targetFile.Content;
            }
```

I get this exception..

```
Octokit.ForbiddenException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=This API returns blobs up to 1 MB in size. The requested blob is too large to fetch via the API, but you can use the Git Data API to request blobs up to 100 MB in size.
```

My question is how to use Git Data API within c# to read the contents of this large file, and further how would I update changes on this file back into the same repository?

Comment: Note: the Get Content API now (May 2022) [supports raw files up to 100MB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72108664/6309)

Answer (score 0):

Well not hard but not so obvious.

My file that I was trying to read/update was 2.4 Mb and while I was able to compress this file down to 512K (using SevenZip) which allowed me to read/update on repo I wanted to read/update files over 1Mb.

To accomplish this I had to use GitHub's GraphQL API.  I required that in order to retrieve the SHA1 for the particular file that I was interested in reading/updating.

Having never worked with Git API or for that matter GraphQL I chose to utilize a GraphQL client (GraphQL.Client and GraphQL.Client.Serializer.Newtonsoft).

With GraphQL I was able to retrieve the SHA-1 id for the existing file/blob in my GitHub Repo.  Once I had the SHA-1 for the blob I was easily able to pull down the file in question via the GIT Data API.

I was then able to alter the content and push the changes back to GitHub via Octokit.Net.

While this is not polished by any means, I wanted to close this with something for anyone else who is attempting to do this.

Credit to the following [stackover flow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58486892/read-image-from-private-github-repository-programmatically-using-c-sharp).

```
public async Task<string> GetSha1(string owner, string personalToken, string repositoryName,  string pathName, string branch = "master")
        {
            string basicValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{owner}:{personalToken}"));

            var graphQLClient = new GraphQLHttpClient("https://api.github.com/graphql", new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());
            graphQLClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", basicValue);

            var getShaRequest = new GraphQLRequest
            {
                Query = @"
                    query {
                      repository(owner: """+owner+@""", name: """+ repositoryName +@""") {
                        object(expression: """ + branch + @":" + pathName +@""") {
                                            ... on Blob {
                                            oid
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }",
                    
                    Variables = new
                    {
                    }
            };

            var graphQLResponse = await graphQLClient.SendQueryAsync<ResponseType>(getShaRequest, cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None);
            return graphQLResponse.Data.Repository.Object.Oid;
        }
```

Here are my helper classes

```
public class ContentResponseType
        {
            public string content { get; set; }
            public string encoding { get; set; }
            public string url { get; set; }
            public string sha { get; set; }
            public long size { get; set; }
        }

        public class DataObject
        {
            public string Oid;
        }

        public class Repository
        {
            public DataObject Object;
        }

        public class ResponseType
        {
            public Repository Repository { get; set; }
        }
```

Here is the file that retrieves the content with the SHA-1 as provided to by method above..

```
 public async Task<ContentResponseType> RetrieveFileAsync(string owner, string personalToken, string repositoryName, string pathName, string branch = "master")
        {
            var sha1 = await this.GetSha1(owner: owner, personalToken: personalToken, repositoryName: repositoryName, pathName: pathName, branch: branch);
            var url = this.GetBlobUrl(owner, repositoryName, sha1);
            var req = this.BuildRequestMessage(url, personalToken);
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var resp = await httpClient.SendAsync(req);
                if (resp.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"error happens when downloading the {req.RequestUri}, statusCode={resp.StatusCode}");
                }
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await resp.Content.CopyToAsync(ms);
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms);
                    var jsonString =  reader.ReadToEnd();
                    return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ContentResponseType>(jsonString);
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is my console test app...

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        // GitHub variables
        var owner = "{Put Owner Name here}";
        var personalGitHubToken = "{Put your Token here}";
        var repo = "{Put Repo Name Here}";
        var branch = "master";
        var referencePath = "{Put path and filename here}";

        // Get the existing Domain Model file
        var api = new GitHubRepoApi();
        var response = await api.RetrieveFileAsync(owner:owner, personalToken: personalGitHubToken, repositoryName: repo, pathName: referencePath, branch:branch);
        var currentFileText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(response.content));

        // Change the description of the JSON Domain Model
        currentFileText = currentFileText.Replace(@"""description"":""SubDomain", @"""description"":""Domain");
        
        // Update the changes back to GitHub repo using Octokit
        var client = new GitHubClient(new Octokit.ProductHeaderValue(repo));
        var tokenAuth = new Credentials(personalGitHubToken);
        client.Credentials = tokenAuth;
        
        // Read back the changes to confirm all works
        var updateChangeSet = await client.Repository.Content.UpdateFile(owner, repo, referencePath,
                                    new UpdateFileRequest("Domain Model was updated via automation", currentFileText, response.sha, branch));
         
        response = await api.RetrieveFileAsync(owner: owner, personalToken: personalGitHubToken, repositoryName: repo, pathName: referencePath, branch: branch);
        currentFileText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(response.content));
    }
```

I am certain there are many other ways to accomplish this but this is what worked for me and I hope this helps to make someone else's life a bit easier.

Cheers
John